# SVG in Keynote?

Tags: keynote

I want to use line art in my Keynote presentations.  [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.svg) is the Scalable Vector Graphics format, used natively by Inkscape.

Is there any way to use an SVG in Keynote, or do I need to convert to a PDF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Now in version 13.1

This is [now possible](https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/add-an-image-tan77aea6844/13.1/mac/1.0) with the recent release of version 13.1, only 9 years after this original question!

Not only can you import them, but you can also [break them apart](https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/combine-or-break-apart-shapes-tane80cfd59d/13.1/mac/1.0) and save them to the shapes library.

See [What’s new in Keynote for Mac | Learn about the new features in Keynote 13.1 for Mac.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207247)

> **Vector graphics**
>
> Add SVG images to your documents and preserve visual quality at any size.
>
> Break apart imported SVG images and save them to your shapes library for future use.

Comment: Now that you can import SVG, is there a way of exporting shapes created in Keynote back out to SVG?

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT** Keynote now supports SVG. The answer below is obsolete.

——-

As of Keynote version 7.2 SVG is not supported without conversion using a third party app. (Would be nice though!)

[image: SVG import to Keynote]

Comment: This is still true for v9.0.1